# Android Studio Delay inside Loop

Tags: java, android, delay

I want to make a loop, the times the user wants but with a delay of 3 seconds.

This is the code:

```
for (i = 0;i < n1; i++){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(KeyMapCreator.this, "Try number " + i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ActionIwantToDo();
                }
            },3000);
        }
```

The **variable i** is the one that the user sets.
The problem is that the toast doesn't show up every 3 seconds, it just do like a normal loop without delay. I thought it was because of the time of the toast but if i set the time to 20 secs still being the same.
Someone knows how to make a proper delay inside a loop???

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that your loop creates many handlers at once that delay for 3 seconds and then show a toast. They do not wait for each other, and because they are created within milliseconds of each other they will show the toast at the same time.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, and a loop is probably not what you want. However this is a way to get the toast to display after 3 seconds and every 3 seconds after for a number of times.

For this we will use recursion because it will make it so that you are not blocked on the main thread.

1. Call doSomething (the recursive function) from where you need the function to start (remember that the second variable is the number of times you want it to run, and 0 is just required as a counter)

```
doSomething(0, 3)
```

2. create doSomething

```
private void doSomething(int i, int n) {
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         if (i < n) {
            Toast.makeText(KeyMapCreator.this, "Try number " + i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            actionIWantToDo();
            doSomething(i+1, n);
         }
      }
   }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: So then how can i make the loop to wait until the action finish to then restart that action?

Comment: I'm not sure a loop is what you need. I edited my answer to show you have to solve this problem recursively. This will allow you to run actionIWantToDo() as many times as you want with a 3000 millisecond delay.

Comment: I have done it too. If i do that, for example, 3 seconds of delay and the user inputs the amount of times to repeat, for example 4 times. It end up with 12 seconds of delay and suddenly 4 times the action collide with itself. Dont know how to solve it

Comment: What do you mean by "the action collide with itself"?

Comment: The action is create a file, but the file takes about a second to create. What i want is to create the amount of files you want, but even using delays, it just create a single file instead of the amount you choose.

Comment: very useful i have had the similar problem which i have done using recursion, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Handler just schedules some work for later execution.  It doesn't actually block the current thread.  All you're doing is scheduling `n1` items of work to execute three seconds later, which will all execute in sequence on that exact delay.

You don't really ever want to write code to block the main thread.  Ever.  It will make your app appear to be unresponsive.

Comment: But if i want to delay the " ActionIwantToDo() " how can i do it inside a loop?

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't do that.  Maybe you just want to increase the delay of each scheduled item of work instead.

Comment: Then how can i make a void repeat a certain number of times without getting the app crashed?(I´m so bad sry)